# Notation minimum of a column vector

Tags: matrices, optimization, notation

I'd like to know the notation to express the minimum of a column vector.

Is this notation correct?

\begin{equation}
\min
\left[\matrix{
   \left|b_{n}-b_{n+1}\right| \cr
   \left|\left(b_{n}+360\right)-b_{n+1}\right| \cr
   \left|b_{n}-\left(b_{n+1}+360\right)\right| \cr
}\right]
\end{equation}

If not, how would i have to write it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need it to be a column vector unless you refer to it elsewhere as being a column vector, in which case I'd give it a name $\mathbf v$ and write $\min_i |v_i|$ or whatever.

If this is the only place it is used, just use the normal $\min\{\cdot,\cdot,\cdot\}$.

It's all personal taste really, I just instinctively feel the above are more natural.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking for the minimum element per se. I think the OP is asking about the element-wise minimum of the vector, i.e., $[\min_n v_1(n)\dots\min_n v_d(n)]$.

Comment: no i'm asking for the element-wise minimum

Comment: thanks i took $min_i$ as i don't have enough space to write them as  a row.